# Mongoose Put method CastError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With the following put mongoose method, I get an error in postman if I do not fill all key/value pair!

```
app.put('/api/users/:user_id', function(req, res) {
    users.update({
        id_userLogin : req.body.id_userLogin,
        userName : req.body.userName,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        userNotes: req.body.userNotes
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        users.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(users);
        });
    });
});
```

It works fine if I put all key/value pair but if it miss one pair, I get

```
"message": "Cast to string failed for value \"undefined\"",
"name": "CastError",
"type": "string"
```

if I add || "" for each params we can update the user with all empty params. In fact if a params is not updated we should keep the initial value

Any help would be appreciated

---

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move the code to for controller

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {
var id = req.params.id
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(user);
    }
});
```

}

and for the route

```
app.route('/api/users/:id').put(users.update);
```

which fix the issue. With this method you can update one of the params

Answer (score 0):

You should check all request parameters for plausibility and discard the request if it is malformed. For non-mandatory params (e.g., `userNotes`), you can set the param to an empty string if it is undefined:

```
app.put('/api/users/:user_id', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.id_userLogin || userName || password) {
        return res.send('Malformed request', 400);
    }
    users.update({
        id_userLogin : req.body.id_userLogin,
        userName : req.body.userName,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        userNotes: req.body.userNotes || ""
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        users.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(users);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I see but how can I do to avoid empty mandatory params initially set during Post. Because if I add || "" for each params we can update the user with all empty params. In fact if a params is not updated we should keep the initial value

Comment: Is it a normal behavior if params are not mandatory in the schema? What is the process to make the request working with param missing? Thanks